# Without potentially disabling foreign keys, how do I have foreign key values repeated without having to disable/remove the foreign key constraint?

Tags: sql, mysql, foreign-keys

```
-- Values for the schedule of all matches that took place

INSERT IGNORE INTO WomenWCSchedule (Bracket, Match_ID, Referee_ID, Team_1, Team_2, Date, Time, Stadium) VALUES
    ('Group Stage A', 'M01', 'R05', 'New Zealand', 'Norway', '2023-07-20', '19:00:00', 'EDEN PARK'),
    ('Group Stage B', 'M02', 'R22', 'Australia', 'Republic of Ireland', '2023-07-20', '20:00:00', 'Stadium Australia'),
    ('Group Stage A', 'M03', 'R06', 'Philippines', 'Switzerland', '2023-07-21', '17:00:00', 'Dunedin Stadium'),
    ('Group Stage B', 'M04', 'R25', 'Nigeria', 'Canada', '2023-07-21', '12:30:00', 'Melbourne Rectangular Stadium'),
    ('Group Stage C', 'M05', 'R02', 'Spain', 'Costa Rica', '2023-07-21', '19:30:00', 'Wellington Regional Stadium'),
    ('Group Stage E', 'M06', 'R07', 'USA', 'Vietnam', '2023-07-22', '13:00:00', 'EDEN PARK'),
    ('Group Stage C', 'M07', 'R23', 'Zambia', 'Japan', '2023-07-22', '19:00:00', 'Waikato Stadium'),
    ('Group Stage D', 'M08', 'R10', 'England', 'Haiti', '2023-07-22', '19:30:00', 'Brisbane Stadium'),
    ('Group Stage D', 'M09', 'R08', 'Denmark', 'China', '2023-07-22', '20:00:00', 'Perth Rectangular Stadium'),
    ('Group Stage F', 'M10', 'R24', 'France', 'Jamaica', '2023-07-23', '20:00:00', 'Sydney Football Stadium'),
    ('Group Stage E', 'M11', 'R21', 'Netherlands', 'Portugal', '2023-07-23', '19:30:00', 'Dunedin Stadium'),
    ('Group Stage G', 'M12', 'R02', 'Sweden', 'South Africa', '2023-07-23', '17:00:00', 'Wellington Regional Stadium'),
    ('Group Stage G', 'M13', 'R26', 'Italy', 'Argentina', '2023-07-24', '18:00:00', 'EDEN PARK'),
    ('Group Stage H', 'M14', 'R08', 'Germany', 'Morocco', '2023-07-24', '18:30:00', 'Melbourne Rectangular Stadium'),
    ('Group Stage F', 'M15', 'R30', 'Brazil', 'Panama', '2023-07-24', '20:30:00', 'Hindmarsh Stadium'),
    ('Group Stage H', 'M16', 'R10', 'Colombia', 'South Korea', '2023-07-25', '12:00:00', 'Sydney Football Stadium'),
    ('Group Stage A', 'M17', 'R02', 'New Zealand', 'Philippines', '2023-07-25', '17:30:00', 'Wellington Regional Stadium'),
    ('Group Stage A', 'M18', 'R27', 'Switzerland', 'Norway', '2023-07-25', '20:00:00', 'Waikato Stadium'),
    ('Group Stage C', 'M19', 'R03', 'Spain', 'Zambia', '2023-07-26', '19:30:00', 'EDEN PARK'),
    ('Group Stage C', 'M20', 'R31', 'Japan', 'Costa Rica', '2023-07-26', '17:00:00', 'Dunedin Stadium'),
    ('Group Stage B', 'M21', 'R08', 'Canada', 'Republic of Ireland', '2023-07-26', '20:00:00', 'Perth Rectangular Stadium'),
    ('Group Stage E', 'M22', 'R02', 'USA', 'Netherlands', '2023-07-27', '13:00:00', 'Wellington Regional Stadium'),
    ('Group Stage E', 'M23', 'R09', 'Portugal', 'Vietnam', '2023-07-27', '19:30:00', 'Waikato Stadium'),
    ('Group Stage B', 'M24', 'R28', 'Australia', 'Nigeria', '2023-07-27', '20:00:00', 'Brisbane Stadium'),
    ('Group Stage D', 'M25', 'R03', 'England', 'Denmark', '2023-07-28', '18:30:00', 'Sydney Football Stadium'),
    ('Group Stage G', 'M26', 'R29', 'Argentina', 'South Africa', '2023-07-28', '12:00:00', 'Dunedin Stadium'),
    ('Group Stage D', 'M27', 'R10', 'China', 'Haiti', '2023-07-28', '20:30:00', 'Hindmarsh Stadium'),
    ('Group Stage G', 'M28', 'R24', 'Sweden', 'Italy', '2023-07-29', '19:30:00', 'Wellington Regional Stadium'),
    ('Group Stage F', 'M29', 'R01', 'France', 'Brazil', '2023-07-29', '20:00:00', 'Brisbane Stadium'),
    ('Group Stage F', 'M30', 'R08', 'Panama', 'Jamaica', '2023-07-29', '20:30:00', 'Perth Rectangular Stadium'),
    ('Group Stage A', 'M31', 'R34', 'Norway', 'Philippines', '2023-07-30', '19:00:00', 'EDEN PARK'),
    ('Group Stage H', 'M32', 'R05', 'Germany', 'Colombia', '2023-07-30', '19:30:00', 'Sydney Football Stadium'),
    ('Group Stage A', 'M33', 'R14', 'Switzerland', 'New Zealand', '2023-07-30', '19:00:00', 'Dunedin Stadium'),
    ('Group Stage H', 'M34', 'R15', 'South Korea', 'Morocco', '2023-07-30', '14:00:00', 'Hindmarsh Stadium'),
    ('Group Stage B', 'M35', 'R16', 'Canada', 'Australia', '2023-07-31', '20:00:00', 'Melbourne Rectangular Stadium'),
    ('Group Stage C', 'M36', 'R15', 'Japan', 'Spain', '2023-07-31', '19:00:00', 'Wellington Regional Stadium'),
    ('Group Stage C', 'M37', 'R02', 'Costa Rica', 'Zambia', '2023-07-31', '19:00:00', 'Waikato Stadium'),
    ('Group Stage B', 'M38', 'R33', 'Republic of Ireland', 'Nigeria', '2023-07-31', '20:00:00', 'Brisbane Stadium'),
    ('Group Stage E', 'M39', 'R16', 'Portugal', 'USA', '2023-08-01', '19:00:00', 'EDEN PARK'),
    ('Group Stage E', 'M40', 'R17', 'Vietnam', 'Netherlands', '2023-08-01', '19:00:00', 'Dunedin Stadium'),
    ('Group Stage D', 'M41', 'R03', 'Haiti', 'Denmark', '2023-08-01', '19:00:00', 'Perth Rectangular Stadium'),
    ('Group Stage D', 'M42', 'R04', 'China', 'England', '2023-08-01', '20:30:00', 'Hindmarsh Stadium'),
    ('Group Stage F', 'M43', 'R18', 'Panama', 'France', '2023-08-02', '20:00:00', 'Sydney Football Stadium'),
    ('Group Stage F', 'M44', 'R06', 'Jamaica', 'Brazil', '2023-08-02', '20:00:00', 'Melbourne Rectangular Stadium'),
    ('Group Stage G', 'M45', 'R18', 'South Africa', 'Italy', '2023-08-02', '19:00:00', 'Wellington Regional Stadium'),
    ('Group Stage G', 'M46', 'R02', 'Argentina', 'Sweden', '2023-08-02', '19:00:00', 'Waikato Stadium'),
    ('Group Stage H', 'M47', 'R19', 'South korea', 'Germany', '2023-08-03', '20:00:00', 'Brisbane Stadium'),
    ('Group Stage H', 'M48', 'R08', 'Morocco', 'Colombia', '2023-08-03', '18:00:00', 'Perth Rectangular Stadium'),
    ('Round of 16', 'M49', 'R20', 'Switzerland', 'Spain', '2023-08-05', '17:00:00', 'EDEN PARK'),
    ('Round of 16', 'M50', 'R21', 'Japan', 'Republic of Ireland', '2023-08-05', '17:00:00', 'Wellington Regional Stadium'),
    ('Round of 16', 'M51', 'R03', 'Netherlands', 'South Africa', '2023-08-06', '12:00:00', 'Sydney Football Stadium'),
    ('Round of 16', 'M52', 'R04', 'Sweden', 'USA', '2023-08-06', '19:00:00', 'Melbourne Rectangular Stadium'),
    ('Round of 16', 'M53', 'R32', 'England', 'Nigeria', '2023-08-07', '17:30:00', 'Brisbane Stadium'),
    ('Round of 16', 'M54', 'R11', 'Australia', 'Denmark', '2023-08-07', '20:30:00', 'Stadium Australia'),
    ('Round of 16', 'M55', 'R01', 'Colombia', 'Jamaica', '2023-08-08', '18:00:00', 'Melbourne Rectangular Stadium'),
    ('Round of 16', 'M56', 'R13', 'France', 'Morocco', '2023-08-08', '20:30:00', 'Hindmarsh Stadium'),
    ('Quarter Finals', 'M57', 'R14', 'Japan', 'Sweden', '2023-08-11', '19:30:00', 'EDEN PARK'),
    ('Quarter Finals', 'M58', 'R32', 'Spain', 'Netherlands', '2023-08-11', '13:00:00', 'Wellington Regional Stadium'),
    ('Quarter Finals', 'M59', 'R07', 'Australia', 'France', '2023-08-12', '17:00:00', 'Brisbane Stadium'),
    ('Quarter Finals', 'M60', 'R03', 'England', 'Colombia', '2023-08-12', '20:30:00', 'Stadium Australia'),
    ('Semi Finals', 'M61', 'R12', 'Spain', 'Sweden', '2023-08-15', '20:00:00', 'EDEN PARK'),
    ('Semi Finals', 'M62', 'R13', 'Australia', 'England', '2023-08-16', '20:00:00', 'Stadium Australia'),
    ('3rd Place', 'M63', 'R18', 'Sweden', 'Australia', '2023-08-19', '18:00:00', 'Brisbane Stadium'),
    ('Final', 'M64', 'R05', 'Spain', 'England', '2023-08-20', '20:00:00', 'Stadium Australia');
    
-- Values for the referees who were assigned 

INSERT IGNORE INTO Officials (Referee_ID, RefereeName) VALUES
    ('R01', 'Kate Jacewicz'),
    ('R02', 'Kim Yu-Jeong'),
    ('R03', 'Oh Hyeon-Jeong'),
    ('R04', 'Casey Reibelt'),
    ('R05', 'Yoshimi Yamashita'),
    ('R06', 'Vincentia Amendome'),
    ('R07', 'Bouchra Karboubi'),
    ('R08', 'Akhona Makalima'),
    ('R09', 'Salima Mukansanga'),
    ('R10', 'Marianela Araya'),
    ('R11', 'Marie Soleil'),
    ('R12', 'Melissa Borjas'),
    ('R13', 'Katia Garcia'),
    ('R14', 'Ekaterina Koroleva'),
    ('R15', 'Myriam Marcotte'),
    ('R16', 'Tori Marcotte'),
    ('R17', 'Tori Penso'),
    ('R18', 'Edina Alves Batista'),
    ('R19', 'Emikar Calderas Barrera'),
    ('R20', 'Maria Carvajal'),
    ('R21', 'Anahi Fernandez'),
    ('R22', 'Laura Fortunato'),
    ('R23', 'Anna Marie Keighley'),
    ('R24', 'Iuliana Demetrescu'),
    ('R25', 'Maria Sole Ferrieri'),
    ('R26', 'Cheryl Foster'),
    ('R27', 'Stephanie Frappart'),
    ('R28', 'Marta Huerta De Aza'),
    ('R29', 'Lina Lehtovaara'),
    ('R30', 'Ivana Martincic'),
    ('R31', 'Kateryna Monzula'),
    ('R32', 'Tess Olofsson'),
    ('R33', 'Esther Staubli'),
    ('R34', 'Rebecca Welch');

-- Values for the stadium Stats

INSERT IGNORE INTO Stadium (Stadium, Location, Capacity) VALUES
('EDEN PARK', 'Auckland', 43217),
('Stadium Australia', 'Sydney', 75784),
('Dunedin Stadium', 'Dunedin', 25947),
('Melbourne Rectangular Stadium', 'Melbourne', 27706),
('Wellington Regional Stadium', 'Wellington', 33132),
('Waikato Stadium', 'Hamilton', 18009),
('Perth Rectangular Stadium', 'Perth', 18727),
('Sydney Football Stadium', 'Sydney', 40583),
('Hindmarsh Stadium', 'Adelaide', 13557),
('Brisbane Stadium', 'Brisbane', 49461);
```

So in the Officials table I have referee_ID as the primary key, and that primary key is referenced into the WomenWCSchedule as a foreign key. Now since it is a foreign key, any repeated values of that will be deemed as duplicate and won't load in the table. I want to know how I can keep the foreign key constraint while allowing repeated values of the referee_ID in the WomenWCSchedule.

I first tried to remove the INSERT IGNORE but that only gave more errors since I am using key constraints. So the INSERT IGNORE needs to exist. I also know I can remove the foreign key constraint but I do not want to do that. Let's just say that it is NEEDED for this, so I want to keep it and at the same time allow for repeated values of it.

I will provide the code for the tables of them both below:

```
-- Drop table if it exists and then create a list of referees and their ID
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Officials;
CREATE TABLE Officials
(
    Referee_ID VARCHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY, -- Unique identifier for the referee
    RefereeName VARCHAR(50) -- Name of the referee
);

-- Drop table if it exists and then create the full 2023 WC schedule
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS WomenWCSchedule; 
CREATE TABLE WomenWCSchedule
(
    Match_ID VARCHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY, -- Unique identifier for the match
    Bracket VARCHAR(20), -- Tournament bracket
    Referee_ID VARCHAR(5), -- Foreign key referencing Officials table
    Team_1 VARCHAR(20), -- Team 1 participating in the match
    Team_2 VARCHAR(20), -- Team 2 participating in the match
    Date DATE, -- Date of the match
    Time TIME, -- Time of the match
    Stadium VARCHAR(30), -- Foreign key referencing Stadium table
    FOREIGN KEY (Referee_ID) REFERENCES Officials(Referee_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (Stadium) REFERENCES Stadium(Stadium)
);
-- Drop table if it exists and then create stats on the venues at the world cup
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Stadium;
CREATE TABLE Stadium
(
    Stadium VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY, -- Unique identifier for the stadium
    Location VARCHAR(20), -- Location of the stadium
    Capacity INT -- Capacity of the stadium
);
```

Comment: disable the foreign  keys and the e3nable them again

Comment: You didn't show the `Stadium` table.

Comment: It works for me without IGNORE if I do it in this order: 1. DROP WomenWCSchedule 2. DROP Officials 3. CREATE Officials 4. INSERT Officials 5. DROP Stadium 6. INSERT Stadium 7. CREATE WomenWCSchedule 8. INSERT WomenWCSchedule.

Comment: What if I had the tables in a separate sql file and the insert values in another sql file? How would that work without IGNORE? Or can it not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now since it is a foreign key, any repeated values of that will be deemed as duplicate and won't load in the table. [...] I want to know how I can keep the foreign key constraint while allowing repeated values of the referee_ID in the WomenWCSchedule.

**You seem to be mistaken as to what foreign keys do.** If WomenWCSchedule.Referee_ID references Officials.Referee_ID, then this means that you cannot have a WomenWCSchedule.Referee_ID that does not exist as a Officials.Referee_ID. That's all. **It does not forbid you to have the same Referee_ID many times in the WomenWCSchedule.**

It would be weird if it did, because Officials is the parent table here, where each official could naturally be referenced more than once in its child table (1:n relation).

Here ist a demo with the inserts without any `IGNORE` clause, and they work just fine: https://dbfiddle.uk/7vvr8xbO

Comment: when I tried running without IGNORE, I get the following error:
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`FINAL`.`WomenWCSchedule`, CONSTRAINT `WomenWCSchedule_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Referee_ID`) REFERENCES `Officials` (`Referee_ID`))

Comment: But you have seen the demo where it works? Of course you must first have the data in the parent tables, before you can insert rows in the child table. (You have this in the wrong order in your request.)

Comment: So what you mean is I need to have the order as Officials, Stadium, WomenWCSchdedule then yes? However, that is the order that I have it in, in my Tables SQL file. I have the Officials table first, followed by the Stadium table, then I have another table for PlayerList (which is not mentioned here) and then the WomenWCSchedule. Could it be that I need to put WomenWCSchedule before PlayerList as well?

Comment: Well, when creating the tables, you first create the parent tables then their child tables. There must be Officials and Stadiums in order to create the WomenWCSchedule table, because it references above tables in its foreign keys. The same goes for inserting rows. As the foreign keys say: "Prevent inserts of Officials and Stadiums that are not in the respective tables", you must of course insert the Officials and Stadiums before inserting the WomenWCSchedule. It is always the parent table first, the child table second. I don't know whether PlayerList is a parent or child to the other tables.

Comment: Thank you for your insight, I was able to figure out a working solution by following your points. I appreciate that you bared with me through this ordeal. I'm still quite new to sql so I wasn't all familiar with the rules. Again, thanks.